# Select some rows of a html table and sent the values of one column of selected rows to another php page when clicking a link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a requirement to select some rows of a html table and sent the values of one column of selected rows to another php page when clicking a link. How it can be done?

With a form i can store values in an form element array and can send to a php array vairable when clicking submit button. but in this case it has to pass through a link.

```
<?php 
$query2="select * from products";
$result2=mysqli_query($connection, $query2);
?>
      <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" id="0" /></th>   
        <th>Item</th>   
        <th>Date</th>   
        <th>Type</th>   
        <th>Price</th>   
        <th>SKU</th>   
        <th>Description</th>   
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php
$i=1;
while($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
{
?>  
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="<?php $i; ?>" name="check['<?php echo $i; ?>']" value="<?php echo $row2['id']; ?>"/></td>
            <td>$row2['item']</td>
            <td>$row2['date']/td>
            <td>$row2['type']</td>
            <td>$row2['price']</td>
            <td>$row2['sku']</td>
            <td>$row2['description']</td>
        </tr>
<?php
$i++;
}
?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<a href="index.php?page=reviewselecteditems">Review Selected Items</a>
```

I want to store "Item" column values of the selected rows in a variable and need to pass it to another php file where i want to fetch aall related details of the selected items from database like amount, tax etc and display it in a html table.

Comment: Try using tableToJson, btw why is php tagged here?

Comment: The values of the rows in the table are actually retrieved from mysql database and in the next page when clicking the link will also get the selected values to be stored in a php array variable.

Answer (score 0):

set the products id in the id attribute and on the click of review button send those ids in the GET method to the next page and there user `$_GET` to retrieve those ids and from those ids execute the sql query to get particular products

it will redirect something like this:

http://localhost/yourpage?id=1,2,3

and get this ids and explode them.